# why strtok() work slower than sscanf

Tags: c, regex

I'm doing our homework... And I found that my code work slower than my classmate's.

Spending some time seeing what's different between our code, I found my load file work much slower than his. He use regex to parse string

The buckets.in and homework spec can be download here
http://cial.csie.ncku.edu.tw/course/2013_Fall_Programming/download/hw4.rar

This is my original code
http://codepad.org/7atC1hY9

my code with my classmate's inputting method
http://codepad.org/jNfqr5Mc

See line 94

```
//Parse it with space
char *p=strtok(buffer, " ");
while(p!=NULL){
    if(*p!='\n'&&*p!='\0')
        buckets[count].data[buckets[count].N++]=atoi(p);
    p=strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

vs

```
for(;sscanf(buffer, "%d %[1234567890 ]", &buckets[count].data[buckets[count].N], buffer)>1;buckets[count].N++);
```

This is my classmate's code http://codepad.org/MMI18Dlz

Also, it seems he did not do anything do improve performance on bucket mapping, but it just run a lot faster than mine. (maybe n is too small...)

Comment: So now does he use regexes or `sscanf()`?

Comment: Also, I see a couple of `printf()` calls in your code. Are you sure that using `sscanf()` (or regexes?) versus `strtok()` is the real bottleneck? Couldn't it be the calls to `printf()` or an algorithmic improvement in your classmate's code?

Comment: I've uploaded my classmate's code here. His answer is wrong because quicksort is not a stable sorting algorithm.(so i added original index in compare function)

Comment: NO I use his sscanf method in my code too, see http://codepad.org/jNfqr5Mc, and i truly read faster

Comment: `int (*odata)[n]=malloc(n*MAX_BUCKETS*sizeof(int));`, this is wrong!
the type specify by you is expecting a pointer to function which is not what you want. You should modify also the function definition. However, this is not the cause of your low performance! Still investigating :D

Comment: I think I've found the answer - MinGW produces bigger and slower code on windows. I just tested them again on Ubuntu 13.10 on virtual machine. My version of both read_buckets(strtok) and new_mapping has better performance than my classmate's and even takes less time than  on windows

Comment: @GiuseppePes odata is a pointer to n-element array of int

Comment: @TimHsu, what you have specified is **not** an array of `int`! The type for an int array is `int []`. That is wrong! It works because they have the same pointer size, but it is a type error.

Comment: When you define a two dimensional array. int a[5][6]; the type of a is int (*)[6];